# Multiple dynamic FIND_IN_SET searches

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have an array like this in my programming language:

```
$animalsToSearch = ['fox', 'cat', 'dog'];
```

And I have a MySQL database table like this:

```
id  | value
----+----------------
1   | dog,elephant
2   | cat,dog
3   | spider,fox,cat
4   | cat
5   | dog,rabit
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the table to be more relational (yet).

I want to pull out how many times an item in my array is present in the database `value` column. Now, the obvious way to do this would be something like:

```
<?php
$count = [];

foreach (['fox', 'cat', 'dog'] as $animal) {
    $count[$animal] = some_function_that_gets_the_data($animal);
}
```

But there might be dozens of animals to search for, and I don't want to send a db request per animal. I have thought of the way below, and then using PHP to look at the values to see if the animal is present within... but it's a bit hacky. Might there be a better way?

```
select
    `value`
from
    `animal`
where
       find_in_set('fox', value)
    or find_in_set('cat', value)
    or find_in_set('dog', value);
```

---

ysth's solution `explain`'d

```
id  select_type  table       partitions    type  possible_keys  key   key_len  ref    rows       filtered  Extra
1   PRIMARY      <derived2>  NULL          ALL   NULL           NULL  NULL     NULL   2          100.00    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY      animal      NULL          ALL   NULL           NULL  NULL     NULL   1,879,296  100.00    Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2   DERIVED      NULL        NULL          NULL  NULL           NULL  NULL     NULL   NULL       NULL      No tables used
3   UNION        NULL        NULL          NULL  NULL           NULL  NULL     NULL   NULL       NULL      No tables used
```

Comment: Yes, there is a better way.  Do not store comma-delimited values in SQL.  Use a separate table with one row per value.

Comment: I fear you missed my comment of "Unfortunately, I cannot change the table to be more relational (yet)." This is a system I have inherited from previous developers.

Comment: Sometimes I think there's one guy roaming from company to company, ruining databases, and making some other hapless developer "inherit" his messes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join against your list:

```
select animallist.animal, count(*) as times
from (
    select 'fox' as animal union all select 'cat' union all select 'dog'
) animallist
join animal on find_in_set(animallist.animal, animal.value)
group by animallist.animal
```

You can try forcing it to only read through animal once, I don't know if that will make it faster or slower:

```
select straight_join animallist.animal, count(*) as times
from animal on find_in_set(animallist.animal, animal.value)
join (
    select 'fox' as animal union all select 'cat' union all select 'dog'
) animallist
group by animallist.animal
```

Comment: Interesting. I had to add `group by animal` to get it to be grouped, though. Only issue is it takes a long time to run (2 seconds), compared to ~30ms of my original posts query :(

Comment: sorry, forgot that. re 2 seconds, what does `explain select ...` show?

Comment: Have added it to my original post (also added in comma to the 1.8 million figure for easy reading).

Comment: added an alternative

Comment: No type of join will allow find_in_set() to do anything other than a table-scan. Performance will be terrible regardless of the type of join you use.

Comment: @BillKarwin right, but the OP's original query was apparently doing a table scan in much less time.  and doing a table scan multiple times (if that's what it is doing) is much worse than once

Comment: Your solution does a table-scan, but also creates a temp table for your subquery and joins against that. That must be more work for the query than only a table-scan against one table.

Comment: Actually, I was able to get your original query to roughly the same time (~40ms) as my horrible original by filtering out a few of the rows by its other columns that were not needed. Fantastic work.

Answer (score 0):

A conventional index cannot help improve the performance of `FIND_IN_SET()` just like an index cannot help improve `SUBSTRING()` or `LIKE` with wildcards. The performance will never be good, and will get worse the larger your table grows.

But a fulltext index can help.

```
ALTER TABLE animals ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (value);

mysql> select * from animals where match(value) against ('rabbit' in boolean mode);
+----+--------------+
| id | value        |
+----+--------------+
|  5 | doggy,rabbit |
+----+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from animals where match(value) against ('rabbit doggy' in boolean mode);
+----+----------------+
| id | value          |
+----+----------------+
|  5 | doggy,rabbit   |
|  1 | doggy,elephant |
|  2 | kittycat,doggy |
+----+----------------+
```

For my test I made all the animal names at least 4 characters, because the default `ft_min_word_len` is 4 characters. Words shorter than that aren't indexed by a FULLTEXT index.

Read the sections on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html for more information.